# What is the ideal time to stay at a job?

Tags: salary, job-change, raise

What would be the ideal time to stay at a job? I have heard that changing jobs too often (for pay raises) puts the loyalty of the employee in question.

This in turn makes prospect employers reluctant to employ someone because they think they will leave as soon as a better offer is out there.

I have heard that 2 years or even 3 years are the ideal timeframe. I am not asking for opinions, I'm asking for (if possible) definite answers based on experiences in HR or something of the sort.

Comment: This has been asked before and I've voted to close it as a duplicate of [How long to stay put?](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/47805/how-long-to-stay-put). The second question in this post is discussed here: [How much time in between companies you are in will you be considered a “Job Hopper?”](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/17119/how-much-time-in-between-companies-you-are-in-will-you-be-considered-a-job-hopp)

Comment: Depends on location and very much depends on the individual employer looking at it. Three years is what is deemed solid here.